# Facebook canvas PHP SDK getLoginUrl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i am runnig a site with PHP-SDK connection to the Facebook. I can figure out, what is wrong:

1. New user comes to the mysite url and uses a button to log in using facebook.
2. Facebook asks for permisions. User accepts.
3. All i sok.

But:

1. New user comes to the Facebok Canvas application and uses a button to log in using facebook (I do not use the Javascript and donť want to.).
2. Nothing happens, it seems that facebook calls the url (getLoginUrl) but it doesn't show the page, where user can allow the permission.

I use:

```
  $params = array(
              'canvas' => 1,
              'fbconnect' => 0,
              'scope' => 'user_about_me, email, publish_stream, read_stream',
              'redirect_uri' => http:/my_domain.com,
              'display' => 'page'
            );
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

I tried to use:

```
             'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/app_namespace/',
```

But it doesn't work, either. Anybody any ideas?

Thanks a lot...

**EDITED:** I tried to use javascript: top.location.href = ... it works, but only if I use as redirect_uri - htttp://domain.com, so the user is no longer in facebook canvas application :( I think it is possible that I use it wrong way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the redirect uri to the canvas URL you can get the user's Access Token with

```
$facebook->getSignedRequest();
```